# Strange Limit - Average Speed of Car

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits

I've been working on a problem I came up with on my own. Long story short, the problem is:

What's the average speed of a car starting at $A$ mph and ending at $B$ mph assuming the car only travels at speed $x_k$ mph for $t(x_k)$ hours, where $\large  t(x_k)=\frac{M*(G_k-G_{k-1})}{x_k} $. Here, $M$ represents the mpg of the car, which is assumed to be constant and independent of speed with $M>0$. $G_k$ represents the amount of fuel remaining when the car is traveling at $x_k$ mph, with $G_0>0$ and $G_n=0$. Note that the units hash out: (gallons*mpg)/mph=hours.

Anyway, I've worked out the formulas and have come up with a final answer. That said, my derivation/proof is missing the final step: evaluating a certain limit.

The limit looks like:

$$\Large
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n}{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\left( \frac{n}{Bk+A(n-k)} \right)}\right)\stackrel{?}{=}\frac{B-A}{ln(B)-ln(A)}
$$

Where A and B are constants such that B>A>0.

I guessed at the limit after noticing that the infinite sum in the denominator can be simplified as 
$\large\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{x_k}
$ where $x_0=A$ and $x_n=B$ and all $x_k$ are just even "steps" from $x_0=A$ to $x_n=B$.

From there:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\large\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{x_k}=\int_{A}^{B} \frac{1}{x} dx = ln(B)-ln(A).
$$

So that gave us the limit of the denominator. What am I missing on how to get the $B-A$ in the numerator? After getting the denominator, I tried a lot of things until I found this limit and checked it against a lot of different numbers in Excel. I'm fairly certain this is the actual limit, but I don't know how to prove it as I'm stuck at the $B-A$ in the numerator...

Anyway, I think this is a really cool result since the answer is independent of however many gallons gas you start with $(G_0>0; G_n=0)$ and also independent of the car's mpg rating $(M>0)$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe you have
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{n}{\displaystyle\sum^n_{k=1}\left(\frac{n}{Bk+A(n-k)}\right)}\right) = \left(\frac{1}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{k=1}\left(\frac{1}{B(k/n)+A(1-k/n)}\right)}\right)
\end{align}
So in the limit you get that
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{n}{\displaystyle\sum^n_{k=1}\left(\frac{n}{Bk+A(n-k)}\right)}\right)=\frac{1}{\displaystyle \int^1_0\frac{1}{Bx+A(1-x)}\ dx}.
\end{align}
Next, observe
\begin{align}
\int^1_0 \frac{1}{A+(B-A)x}\ dx = \frac{\log(A+(B-A)x)}{B-A}\bigg|^1_0 = \frac{\log B-\log A}{B-A}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks Jacky this looks great! I'm sorry I'm bad at limits, but can you explain the step of how $$\large \frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{B(k/n)+A(1-k/n)}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{Bx+A(1-x)} dx$$

Comment: @Andrew write $\int^1_0 \frac{1}{Bx + A(1-x)} dx$ in Riemann sum.

Comment: Thanks! I got it now. I think it's more intuitive if we write the denominator as: $A+(B-A)(\frac{k}{n})$ then that clearly becomes $(A+(B-A)x) \,dx$